# dotnet publish. Determ if is published version running while runtime

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-7.0

Lets say I run

`dotnet publish --configuration Release or Debug ...`

Can I determ in code that this is an Published version?

I would like to have something like this.

`if(<something>.IsPublished && !hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction()) throw new NotSupportedException("Published apps support only Production environment"`

I'm aware of Debug,Release switches. This is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Create a configuration or configurations besides Release/Debug and in that configuration set a certain Assembly Attribute that you can then check for at runtime. For example you could use the AssemblyDescription attribute to write something like "Production Build", "Test Build", "Staging Build" etc. in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a separate configuration other than Debug & Release would allow you to have compile-time checks. I.e. you can have code that won't even exist in your `Debug`/`Release` build.

Let's create one called `Published`.
Depending how you manage your projects, there are several ways to do this.

---

#### If you use VS and a solution file

Right-click on your solution, and pick `Configuration Manager...`
Under the `Active solution configuration:` dropdown, select `<New...>`

- Name: `Published`
- Copy settings from: `Release`
- Create new project configs: ✔

#### If you are only using a .csproj file with no .sln

Add the following to your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configurations>Debug;Release;Published</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

This will result in the definition of a compile-time symbol called `PUBLISHED`.

You can then use it in a [compile-time check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) like so:

```
#if PUBLISHED
  if(!hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
    throw new NotSupportedException("Sorry..");
#endif
```

You then do your usual `dotnet publish -c Published`